# Include and class PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, include

Guys why doesn't php read my class file? I have this structure:

- home.php
- stamp.php
- class/class.stamp.php
- class/class.text.php

**home.php**

```
<?php

echo "hello i'm the home page";
include 'class/class.stamp.php'
$stamp = new Stamp();

include 'class/class.text.php';

?>
```

**class.text.php**

```
<?php

$stamp->something('hello yes it is');

?>
```

**class.stamp.php**

```
<?php

class Stamp {
  public function something($text);
      echo $text;
  }
}

?>
```

The result? Nothing! It says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function something on a non-object in /bla/bla/bla/

But if i do something like that, it works!

**home.php**

```
<?php

echo "hello i'm the home page";    
include 'class/class.text.php';

?>
```

**class.text.php**

```
<?php

include 'class.stamp.php'
$stamp = new Stamp();
$stamp->something('hello yes it is');

?>
```

**class.stamp.php**

```
<?php

class Stamp {
  public function something($text) {
      echo $text;
  }
}

?>
```

But I don't need that, please guys help me :(

Comment: `include 'class.text.php';` But as you wrote it this is in the directory: `class`

Comment: The files included are relative to the first script you are loading (page you visited). So if you are loading `home.php`, to get at the classes you need to specify the `class` directory. Even if you load home which includes `class/class.stamp.php` which includes `class.text.php`. `stamp` would need to specify the class folder because it is relative to `home.php` which is the page visited.

Comment: sorry, my error, i update the code now. But the problem stille there.

Comment: @RavenJe 1. `include 'class/class.stamp.php'` <- missing semicolon 2. `public function something($text);` <- Change semicolon to `{`

Comment: Yes... guys sorry this is an exemple code, i missed something, now i edit again... the problem still the same sorry.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error! Please make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue is with the directory.

You said it works with class.stamp.php, but shouldn't that be class/class.stamp.php? Here's the thing, if your homepage is located in a certain folder, then *in that same folder location* you should have the folder class, adjacent to your Home.php file.

I've also had the issue of uninstantiated object, so make sure you are including it in every scope. To help you catch the error, use

```
require "class/class.stamp.php";//Throws an error if it can't find the file.
require_once "class/class.stamp.php";//Bad practice
```

If require doesn't help you solve it, post everything please.